# Updating doc links?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-bydesign

I updated a bunch of links to documentation webpages and didn't mean to flood the front page with those updates. Is there a way to do that more silently? Sorry about that!

Comment: Thanks for keeping the links up to date. You missed one: https://mathoverflow.net/a/291124/70594 :P

Comment: to documentation webpages.

Answer (score 4):

It might have been preferred to roll out those edits over a slightly longer period of time; however, it is good to have links and materials updated.

There is no way to update the contents of the post and not bump it (besides some exotic tag-only manipulations available only to moderators in a limited # of situations). While it is sometimes an undesirable effect, this is also an essential feature for community moderation.

Moreover, [Hot Today](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/?tab=hot) and [Hot Week](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/?tab=week) links still work, even if the front page is flooded with the edits.

Comment: Something similar happened when we updated the tags last year. Should we open a discussion on Meta on how to handle this updates?

Comment: @nicoguaro sounds like a good idea. would you formulate?

Comment: Check the post: https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/584/9667