# Procedure to update (several) old posts

Tags: discussion

There are times that there might be an interest in updating several posts. For example, to [update documentation links](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/582/updating-doc-links/583?noredirect=1#comment1926_583) or to [clean up tags](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/518/june-2019-tag-clean-up-initiative). The thing is **what is the appropriate way to do it** since updating all of them in a short period of time will pollute the main page of the site.

So, this post is about the following question:

**What do you think it should be the procedure to update several posts?**

Comment: I understand the problem, but realistically, how often does occur such as to warrant a different procedure.  If people want newer questions at the top, they can opt to sort as such.  Updating questions shouldn’t drown out new posts as long as they sort this way.

Comment: @Paul, it was already [pointed out before](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/546/9667) and that's why I mention it.